# reference for a combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, reference-request, binomial-coefficients

I am new to combinatorics so apologies in advanced for asking a possibly well-known question:  Is there a combinatorial identity for

$$\sum_{i+j=k}   \binom{n}{j} \binom{n-j}{i}  \:\: \text{ where } 0\le i, j\le k\le n \:\: ?$$

Short of that, how might one go about getting (upper) bound of this double sum in terms of $n$ *and* $k$, other that using Stirling approximating?  Many thanks for your help and references!

Comment: $\binom nj\binom {n-j}i$ is the coefficient of $x^iy^jz^{n-k}$ in $(x+y+z)^n.$ So when $y=x,$ we get the sum of these terms is the coefficient of $x^kz^{n-k}$ in $(2x+z)^n,$ which is $2^k\binom nk.$

Comment: So you can see this sum as the number of ordered pairs of disjoint subsets $(S,T)$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that $|S|+|T|=k.$ But that is the same as choosing $V$ of size $k$ and then picking $S\subseteq V$ in $2^k$ ways and $T=V\setminus S.$